# Why ping receives another ping command packet?

Tags: c, linux, ping, raw-sockets

I am learning about the ping implementation in C.
The problem is, I was using a raw sockets to receive the packet. For all packets we have a identification value in `ICMP header`.

I was running the `ping` in multiple terminal.

For example, I was running three `ping google.com` in three terminals.

For the first ping the identification value is 23456, the second ping identification value is 34564, and the third ping identification value is 98763.

My problem is the second ping have to receives the identification with 34564 packet, but it receives the identification value as 23456.

For each ping the new raw socket is creating. But it receives another ping packet.

Can anyone please explain me, why it receives another ping packet ?

UPDATE:-

I have another one doubt. The doubt is,

raw sockets reads the packet from where and how it identify the packet is for this raw socket ?

UPDATE 1:-

Here is the link for the codes.

[ping_common.c](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping_common.c)

[ping.c](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping.c)

[ping.h](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping.h)

Comment: Though I tried, I couldn't spot a problem in the unposted code you're running.

Comment: It is happen in reply packet. Using recvmsg I was receiving packet. After the recvmsg I was validating the packets, in validating, the identification value is changed.

Comment: @suresh : Thanks for info. Now show us some code please..

Comment: @suresh the code you linked is the source of linux `ping` command, they does not have the problem you described. You need to show your own code.

Comment: I am learning this code only. In that they skipped that packets. My doubt is this is the raw socket. Why it receives another socket packets ?

Answer (score 3):

What's you are seeing is by design of the raw socket, because raw sockets are meant to receive all the raw packets. So to only receive the reply to certain ICMP packets, you need to apply filters on the socket. First you can use `ICMP_FILTER` socket options to restrict receiving of certain ICMP types:

```
struct icmp_filter filter;
filter.data = <bit mask of ICMP types, like ICMP_REPLY>;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_RAW, ICMP_FILTER, &filter, sizeof filter)
```

Second, you can attach socket filter to enforce only receive the package with the given ICMP ID:

```
struct sock_fprog filter;
// set filter to check ID with your own ID
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &filter, sizeof filter);
```

Comment: @suresh Two raw sockets are created for two pings.

Comment: The raw sockets doesn't check any condition like reads the packets for this socket only?

Comment: @suresh we are talking about *raw* sockets, there is no such thing as packets for this socket only, raw sockets are for all packets, what you can do is to filtering on your own.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your other doubt:

- raw sockets reads the packet from where and how it identify the packet is for this raw socket ?

Raw socket sit along side other protocol handlers after IP layer. From book "Understanding Linux Network Internals" Chapter 25.5:

> Here are some examples of interactions between protocols:
>
> IP protocol
>
> The ip_local_deliver_finish routine, described in Chapter 24, delivers
> ingress ICMP messages to the receive routine icmp_rcv registered by
> the ICMP protocol, but it also delivers them to the raw IP sockets
> that registered against the ICMP protocol (raw_v4_input).

[image]